# How to make webpack output both commonjs and EMS?

Tags: typescript, webpack

I am trying to build a TypeScript library for server side app using webpack. I want to generate both a commonjs and ESM but didn't find a way to do this.

```js
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/index.ts",
  devtool: "inline-source-map",
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        use: "ts-loader",
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".tsx", ".ts", ".js"],
  },
  output: {
    filename: "index.cjs",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    chunkFormat: 'commonjs',
  }
};
```

How can I generate a `index.mjs` with this webpack config? I tried passing an array to "output".